Multiple Authentication In Net Core
I'm developing a native application consuming a rest api. Currently my rest api protected by JWT bearer. I want to limit a client using my rest ip. The idea is to add the client certificate to every client. Like we want to certify the client app at the same time authenticate the user using this client.
However i can't merge both CertificateAuthenticationDefaults and JwtBearerDefaults. My [Authorize] attribute on my controller only able to accept either CertificateAuthenticationDefaults or JwtBearerDefaults not both scheme at the same time. Any reference to solve this?
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace WebApiKeycloakAndCertificate
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApiKeycloak", Version = "v1" });
        });
        services.AddTransient<CertificateValidation>();
        services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
        {
            authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
        {
            jwtOptions.Authority = "https://dev.company.com/auth/realms/my-realm";
            jwtOptions.Audience = "account";

            jwtOptions.SaveToken = false;
            jwtOptions.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

            jwtOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            
            jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://dev.company.com/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };
        }).AddCertificate(options => {
            options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
            options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnCertificateValidated = context => {
                    var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<CertificateValidation>();
                    if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                    {
                        context.Success();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Fail("Invalid certificate");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
                    context.Fail("Invalid certificate");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebApiKeycloak v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
  }
}
        

And my controller:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Certificate,Bearer")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
}


What you get when calling API? 401? did you add these two lines as well? app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();

return 401 without valid certificate AND valid jwt token. With either valid token or valid certificate return 200. I call both app.UseAuthentication(); and app.UseAuthorization();. I update my question again with full startup code

You want to always check both schemes? I mean for each request should check Certificate AND Bearer?

I would suggest checking this video first, I explained in very detail about authentication scheme, I think you may need a CustomeAuthenticationHandler: https://youtu.be/2rhhlwKO_Xw

found another simple solution using custom attribute inherited from IAuthorizationFilter

In addition to sa-es-ir's answer, you could use a custom AuthenticationSchemeProvider to automatically select the authentication scheme based on something like an http header. In this case you wouldn't need to set the AuthenticationSchemes on every Authorize-Attribute:
public class CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options) : AuthenticationSchemeProvider(options)
{
    public override Task<AuthenticationScheme?> GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync() => GetDefaultSchemeAsync();

    public override Task<AuthenticationScheme?> GetDefaultChallengeSchemeAsync() => GetDefaultSchemeAsync();

    public override Task<AuthenticationScheme?> GetDefaultForbidSchemeAsync() => GetDefaultSchemeAsync();

    public override Task<AuthenticationScheme?> GetDefaultSignInSchemeAsync() => GetDefaultSchemeAsync();

    public override Task<AuthenticationScheme?> GetDefaultSignOutSchemeAsync() => GetDefaultSchemeAsync();

    private Task<AuthenticationScheme?> GetDefaultSchemeAsync()
    {

        var authenticateUsingCertificate = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("authenticate-using-certificate") ?? false;
        if (authenticateUsingCertificate)
        {
            return GetSchemeAsync(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        return GetSchemeAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}


any chances to give more detail? almost all lines give me error mark

@ktary i'm using net8.0 and LangVersion 12 (declared in the .csproj file). the errors could be due to the primary constructor. moving httpContextAccessor and options to a normal constructor could help. if it still doesn't work, tell me the toplevel error
